# matplotlib naming the tick marks on x axis 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Using the same code from a previous question, this sample generates the graph below:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (0, 1890,865, 236, 6, 1, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0)
ind = range(len(data))
width = 0.9   # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, data, width)
plt.xlabel('Duration 2^x')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('DBFSwrite')
plt.axis([0, len(data), -1, max(data)])

ax = plt.gca()

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('myfig')
```

[image: Sample output]

Instead of the tick labels being 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...I would rather have them be labeled at every mark, and proceed with the value of 2^x: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.  How can I do that?  And then even better, could I have the label centered under the bar, instead of at the left edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to make use of a `Locator` and a `Formatter`. This makes it possible to use the plot interactively without "losing" tickmarks. In this case I'd recommend [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) and [`FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) as seen in example below.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FuncFormatter

data = (0, 1890,865, 236, 6, 1, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0)
ind = range(len(data))
width = 0.9   # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

# Add `aling='center'` to center bars on ticks
p1 = plt.bar(ind, data, width, align='center')
plt.xlabel('Duration 2^x')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('DBFSwrite')
plt.axis([0, len(data), -1, max(data)])

ax = plt.gca()

# Place tickmarks at every multiple of 1, i.e. at any integer
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
# Format the ticklabel to be 2 raised to the power of `x`
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: int(2**x)))
# Make the axis labels rotated for easier reading
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('myfig')
```

[image]

Comment: @PhillipCloud I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @tcaswell My mistake. I thought that `FuncFormatter` and `MultipleLocator` were not part of `pyplot`, turns out they are imported with `pyplot`.

Comment: `pyplot` is just a bucket for bulk importing `matplotlib` related stuff.

Answer (score 5):

[`xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) is what you want:

```
# return locs, labels where locs is an array of tick locations and
# labels is an array of tick labels.
locs, labels = xticks()

# set the locations of the xticks
xticks( arange(6) )

# set the locations and labels of the xticks
xticks( arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') )
```

So, to have the ticks at 2^x for x in 1..4, do as follows:

```
tick_values = [2**x for x in arange(1,5)]

xticks(tick_values,[("%.0f" % x)  for x in tick_values])
```

To have the labels centered instead of left of the bars, use the `align='center'` when calling [`bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

Here's the result:

[image: the resulting graph]

Comment: +1 On a side note, there's no need to do `[2**x for x in arange(1,5)]`  It's much more efficient to just do `2**arange(1, 5)`.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for pointing this out! It's just that I'm in love with list comprehensions so I use them whenever I can ;)

Comment: Yes, but you should be more in love with numpy ;)